# Pass an object that has an optional property to a function that guarantee it will not be undefined but editor/compiler still think it can be undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
function f1(
    toolbox: {
       tool1?: Tool1,
       tool2?: Tool2,
    }
) {
    if (!toolbox.tool1) {
        toolbox.tool1 = fetchTool1();
    }
    if (!toolbox.tool2) {
        toolbox.tool2 = fetchTool2();
    }
    // Do something else
}

function f2(
    toolbox: {
        tool1?: Tool1,
        tool2?: Tool2,
    }
) {
    f1(toolbox);
    // tool1 and tool2 are no longer undefined.
    const x = toolbox.tool1.value // Editor shows error, tool1 may be undefined.
}
```

The design above passes a `toolbox` object to different functions, so the program doesn't need to fetch the tools that are already fetched by other functions. The problem is, even if I know for sure `toolbox.tool1` and `toolbox.tool2` will not be undefined after calling `f1`, the editor still shows error.

I know I can use exclamation mark like `const x = toolbox.tool1!.value`, or maybe just turn off the warning. But I'm looking for a way that is more friendly to the default type checking.

I have tried let `f1` return the `toolbox` that has no question mark in it, and call `toolbox = f1(toolbox)`. It doesn't work, the line `const x = toolbox.tool1.value` still shows error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [asserts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

`f1` now looks like this:

```
function f1(
    toolbox: {
       tool1?: Tool1,
       tool2?: Tool2,
    }
): asserts toolbox is { tool1: Tool1; tool2: Tool2 } {
```

You can think of this as "changing" the type in the scope it was called:

```
f1(toolbox);

toolbox // now { tool1: Tool1; tool2: Tool2 }

const x = toolbox.tool1.value; // fine
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wglRvN)

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do I add return type to the function?

Comment: @JeffreyChen What do you mean by that?

Comment: If `f1` was `function f1(toolbox: (skip) ): string {return "xyz";}`, how do I still keep `:string` after adding `asserts`.

Comment: `asserts` functions can't return anything.

Comment: I end up calling an assert function in `f2` after calling `f1`, because I need `f1` to return value. It is not perfect but good enough. This is the correct answer to my original question.